# How can I select the last-child of the last-child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the last child's last child (with text "this one") in a code that looks like this

```
<div class="block">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>this one</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried `.block:last-child:last-child` but it didn't work.
PS: I can't add css classes

Comment: code for your selection?

Comment: try `.block div:last-child div:last-child` by why have you tagged jquery

Comment: `.block > div:last > div:last` Obviously, if you HTML is dynamic then you'll need to implement some logic instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.block div:last-child div:last-child`

```css
.block div:last-child div:last-child{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div>not</div>
  <div>not</div>
  <div>not</div>
  <div>
    <div>not</div>
    <div>not</div>
    <div>this one</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

To target this one you can use the following:

```
.block > :last-child > :last-child {
  background-color: green; 
 }
```

This obviously just creates a green background, change it to whatever you want.

Comment: Best answer since it is not **element type specific**.

Comment: @Paulie_D: There is no reason not to be specific if you know your element types in advance. You might as well add a type selector and save browsers the headache of trying to match this rule against every last child in the document that isn't a div. **If** your element types are known to change, then by all means leave out the type selector.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried .block:last-child:last-child but it didn't work.

You need to give space to get the `last-child` of *child element*

```
".block div:last-child div:last-child"
```

```js
var element = document.querySelector( ".block div:last-child div:last-child" );
console.log( element.innerHTML );
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>this one</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select by following css selector

```css
.block div:last-child div:last-child{
  color:#ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div>Don't Select</div>
  <div>Don't Select</div>
  <div>Don't Select</div>
  <div>
    <div>Don't Selectt</div>
    <div>Don't Select</div>
    <div>This one</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How above selector will select the desire div

- `.block` will select the `element` which should have class `.block`
- then first `div:last-child` selector will select the last child `div` of that element which has `.block` class
- then last `div:last-child` selector will select the last child `div` of that previous child selected `div`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using jquery also

```
$(".block div:last").css({"color","red"});
```